# How to upgrade yarn without node with brew

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, homebrew, yarnpkg

If we are using nvm or ndenv, we use `--ignore-dependencies` option when installing yarn with brew for not install node.

In this case, how to upgrade yarn?

Here are the methods that failed.

```
$ brew upgrade yarn --ignore-dependencies
Error: invalid option: --ignore-dependencies
```

```
$ brew upgrade yarn # node is installed :(
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can self update yarn using the official provided curl script:

```
curl --compressed -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash
```

See more about this [here](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/self-update/)

Answer (score 0):

Just update it using itself!:

`yarn global upgrade yarn`
or :

`yarn global add yarn`

Also you can istall or update it, using `npm`globally.